# R optim - log likelihood estimator and gradient in the same function

Tags: r, optimization, gradient

I have written a function for performing maximum simulated likelihood estimation in R, which works quite well.

However, the problem is that optim does not call the same function for estimating the likelihood value and estimating the gradient at the same time, like the fminuc optimizer in matlab does. Thus every time if optim wants to update the gradient, the simulation for the given parameter vector have to repeated. At the end optim has called about 100 times the loglik function for updating the parameters and in addition 50 times the loglik function for calculating the gradient.

I am wondering if there is an elegant solution to avoid the 50 additional simulation steps, for example by storing the estimated likelihood value and gradient in each step. Then before the likelihood function is called the next time, it is checked if for a given parameter vector the information are available already or not. This could be done by interpose an additional function between optim and the loglik function. But that seems to be bitty.

Any good ideas?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: I know nlm() can do that, but at the end it is slower as optim for any reason.

Comment: Package `memoise` maybe be useful to you. It creates a hash of previous function inputs and stores resulting output. Basically creates the wrapper function you are alluding to.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example that we can replicate.